# Cannot resolve environment variables in Powershell with periods "." in them

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, period

I am trying to access environment variables using Powershell.  The environment variables, which is out of my control, contain periods in this format:

```
ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE.1
```

Therefor, upon assigning the value of the environment variable to a local variable, it looks like this:

```
$myvar = $env:ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE.1
```

However, every time I try to retrieve this variable, it always leaves out the ".1", returning nothing.

I'm aware periods + Bash = no bueno, but again, this is out of my control and I need a work around.  If it helps, I already tried this as well with no luck:

```
$myvar = ${env:ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE.1}
```

I appreciate any and all help on this.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The last format you're using works for me:

```
PS> ls env:\fo*

Name                           Value
----                           -----
Foo.1                          bar.1


PS> ${env:foo.1}
bar.1
```

Comment: OK - it's working for me too.  Which leads me to what is really going on on my end.  My code is in a while loop where Foo.1 is replaced by Foo.$i - $i being an incremented variable - leading my code to look like this: ${env:foo.$i} .  Sorry for my vagueness.  The real problem is why the $i is not resolving to an integer.

Comment: Anything inside curlies will not be normally evaluated such as the `.` to dereference a property or `$` to reference a variable.  Try this instead `set-item "env:\foo.$i" bar.2`. Note that you won't be replacing the env var but will be creating a new one.  You can always use `remove-item` to remove the old env var.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't know if I'm following you.  I don't want to set/remove/manipulate an env var.  All I want is the value of that env var to run a job later.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @user1068261 Ah then try `get-item "env:\foo.$i"`.

Comment: Well, now it doesn't break =)  But now it returns 'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry'.  Gotta look up what that means.  Thanks for the get-item bit.  Didn't know you could set that to a variable.

Comment: @user1068261 The *-Item and *-ItemProperty cmdlets work on various PowerShell providers including the file system provider, registry provider and even the Environment provider.  That is the env:\ behaves kind of like a drive.  You can `cd` to it.  You can even use rename-item and copy-item on environment variables.